# How to access the desktop with cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I want access to my windows 10 desktop with Cygwin. I tried this

```
$cd cygdrive/c/
$ls -al
```

But I can't see no one folder named "Desktop".

Comment: It seems the desktop directory in Cygwin should be:
`/cygdrive/c/Users/[username]/Desktop`, and this do work for me.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered the Desktop for any user is located in the disk at

```
C:\Users\[username]\Desktop
```

and its equivalent for Cygwin is

```
$ cygpath -u 'C:\Users\[username]\Desktop'
/cygdrive/c/Users/[username]/Desktop
```

It is NOT a `Cygwin` specific issue. Also with `Windows Commond Prompt` there is no
`Desktop` folder at the root of the `C:` disk structure

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.472]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.

C:\Users\Marco>cd \

C:\>dir
 Datenträger in Laufwerk C: ist Windows
 Volumeseriennummer: 98EE-C713

 Verzeichnis von C:\

15.07.2018  12:13    <DIR>          inetpub
19.06.2018  16:34    <DIR>          Intel
12.04.2018  00:38    <DIR>          PerfLogs
05.10.2018  12:15    <DIR>          Program Files
30.12.2018  04:27    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
18.07.2018  16:39    <DIR>          SWSetup
18.07.2018  16:51    <DIR>          temp
19.09.2018  10:44    <DIR>          Users
03.01.2019  23:07    <DIR>          Windows
               0 Datei(en),              0 Bytes
               9 Verzeichnis(se), 174.164.725.760 Bytes frei

C:\>
```

Explorer is showing a Virtual structure putting together the User data folders and the Disks at the same level.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that OneDrive is automatically "eating" the Desktop folder. Look here:

/cygdrive/c/users/[user-name]/OneDrive/Desktop.

For me it worked.....